# Tensorflow Dataset map: input seems to be a placeholder which causes an error in tf.read_file

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to read in data using the Tensorflow Dataset API. I have loaded filenames and label filenames into arrays which I load into a dataset. I then try to map these filenames to the actual image files, but get an error that seems to state that the input to the mapping function recieves placeholders rather than actual tensors.

```
class DatasetReader:

def __init__(self, records_list, batch_size=1):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.records = {}
    self.records["image"] =  tf.convert_to_tensor([record['image'] for record in records_list])
    self.records["filename"] =  tf.convert_to_tensor([record['filename'] for record in records_list])
    self.records["annotation"] = tf.convert_to_tensor([record['annotation'] for record in records_list])
    self.dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(self.records)
    self.dataset = self.dataset.map(self._input_parser)
    self.dataset = self.dataset.batch(batch_size)
    self.dataset = self.dataset.repeat()

def _input_parser(self, record):
    filename = record['filename']
    image_name = record['image']
    annotation_file = record['annotation']
    image = tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(filename))
    annotation = tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(annotation_file))
    return self._augment_image(image, annotation)
```

The error I'm getting is in the line `image = tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(filename))`. The stack trace is below.

```
  File "FCN.py", line 269, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "FCN.py", line 179, in main
    train_records, valid_records, image_options_train, image_options_val, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/FCN.tensorflow/TFReader.py", line 89, in from_records
    train_reader = DatasetReader(train_records, train_image_options, train_batch_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/FCN.tensorflow/TFReader.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.dataset = self.dataset.map(self._input_parser)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 964, in map
    return MapDataset(self, map_func, num_threads, output_buffer_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1735, in __init__
    self._map_func.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 449, in add_to_graph
    self._create_definition_if_needed()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/framework/function.py", line 168, in _create_definition_if_needed
    outputs = self._func(*inputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1723, in tf_map_func
    ret = map_func(nested_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/FCN.tensorflow/TFReader.py", line 42, in _input_parser
    image = tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(filename))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 223, in read_file
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("ReadFile", filename=filename, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/framework/function.py", line 80, in create_op
    data_types, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 665, in create_op
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2632, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1911, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1861, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 595, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 659, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [?].
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass in a rank-1 tensor to tf.read_file. Here are some examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Correct: input can be a string.
tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file("filename"))
# Correct: input can be a rank-0 tensor.
tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(tf.convert_to_tensor("filename")))

# Wrong: input cannot be a list.
tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(["filename"]))
# Wrong: input cannot be a rank-1 tensor
tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(tf.convert_to_tensor(["filename"])))
```

In your code, it seems like `self.records["filename"]` is a rank-1 tensor; you might mistakenly passed it as a parameter to `tf.read_file` in `_input_parser`

Comment: Thank you. Am I misunderstanding `map` then? From my understanding, `map` would work like the `map` function in Python, taking as input one element/slice of the tensor and returning the replacement element/slice. Since my input to the dataset is a dictionary of the form `{'image': [list of image names], 'filename':[list of filenames], 'annotations':[list of labels]}` where each element in the dictionary is a 1d array (converted to a rank-1 tensor), each element in the dictionary input of map should be a rank-0 tensor. What am I misunderstanding?